# Regarding fill some empty fields in access table

Tags: ms-access

i have a table like this and now my task is to fill the empty field with respect to vol and country of the respective column

rule  : i have to see the highest volume in the vol field and take the country of that vol and put it in the empty field (ie i have to fill empty cell with country JP because the vol of japan is more )
like this i have to fill .

the remaining fileds like RB , Plant, MCR are changing for remaining empty cells.

i had use Dlookup for this but i coudnt get the solution could any one please help me it is very helpful if you find me the solution.

like this i have to fill all empty line in the table 
[image: my access database table]

Ok i am giving more clear view of my table view so that you can understand easily
[image]
this is the only table i have to do the task 
and now my task is i have to fill the empty cells in the country field but the condition is i should look the RB , Plant ,MCM with respect to vol field (ie: if you see the table the RB , plant ,MCM feilds are same but the country and vol are changing for one group so i have to also consider the fields, that means if the RB, plant, mcm fields are same then i have to  take the one of the country in the group with the highest volume) (i just give example in the first thre rows RB , plant , MCM are same so i have to take the highest volume country ie IN so  the empty cell should be IN and secodn group empty cells should be TH like that i have to fill.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you tried with `DLookup()`.

Comment: what i did was i made the table in two parts one with all empty  fields of country and the other table was all filled lines of country and then i inner join the RB,Plant,mcr of two tables and tried to use Dlookup but i coudnt get the correct logic for Dlookup function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment to Johnny Bones' answer, your original requirement could have been accomplished with an UPDATE statement that used the `DLookup()` and `DMax()` functions like this:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable 
SET Country=DLookup("Country","MyTable","Vol=" & DMax("Vol","MyTable")) 
WHERE Country IS NULL
```

Even with your revised requirements it is still possible, just more scary-looking:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable 
SET Country=DLookup("Country","MyTable","RB='" & RB & "' AND Plant='" & Plant & "' AND MCM='" & MCM & "' AND Country IS NOT NULL AND Vol=" & Nz(DMax("Vol","MyTable","RB='" & RB & "' AND Plant='" & Plant & "' AND MCM='" & MCM & "' AND Country IS NOT NULL"),0)) 
WHERE Country IS NULL
```

The above query was tested and verified as working in Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in VBA, and have more control over how it reacts.  Something like this will do:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Dim MySQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select Top 1 MyTable.Country FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyTable.Vol DESC")

MyCountry = rec(0)

rec.Close
SetWarnings = False

MySQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET MyTable.Country = '" & MyCountry & "' WHERE IsNull(MyTable.Country) or Len(MyTable.Country) < 2"
DoCmd.RunSQL MySQL

SetWarnings = True
db.Close
```

I tested the above and it works, although if your table's field's properties are different you may need to tweak some of the code.

Obviously, anywhere you see "MyTable" you should use your own table's name.

Comment: Actually, it *can* be done with an UPDATE query using `DLookup()` (along with `DMax()`), which is why I asked the OP to show what they had tried. `UPDATE MyTable SET Country=DLookup("Country","MyTable","Vol=" & DMax("Vol","MyTable")) WHERE Country IS NULL`

Comment: DLookup won't put a lock on the table?  I didn't actually try it myself, I had tried using a nested SELECT statement and that created a non-updateable query.

Comment: When i am trying to execute the update query it displays "UNKNOWN" message box why ?

Comment: UPDATE [Table] SET Country =DLookup("Country","[Table]","Vol= " & DMax("Vol","[Table]"))
WHERE Country IS NULL;        when i am executing this query i am getting error message like syntax error (comma) in query expression vol=823,6523  like this it displays could any one please help me out and i am also getting unknown messgae box after that

Comment: @RaghuPandu - My code works exactly with the example you've given.  If your data actually looks different, please edit your post and put some actual data in there.  All I can do is give answers based on what I see.  If you're referring to Gord's code, I can't help you because I don't use it.

Comment: @johnny Bones hello as you said i updated my question with clear instruction could you help me out now please

Comment: @JohnnyBones No, domain aggregate functions don't lock the tables so they can be used in UPDATE queries as I described.

Comment: So what data type is Vol?  Text?

Comment: @Grod thompson your update query is perfectly working but a small question can i use your update query on the other query because i have to do some filtering on the table before using update qury is it possible to do are i can only do the update query directly on the main table can you please clarify my doubt

Comment: Because when i directly update the table i dont know why it is not updating it shows " you are about to update 0 rows " my table has total 9000 lines what happened can any one guide me please.

Comment: @RaghuPandu - If you do it in VBA, as I suggested, you can use SetWarnings to get rid of those messages.  See my edit above.  You can also do any additional filtering as needed.

Comment: Hello @Jhonny Bones i put the Gord Thompson logic in your code could you please correct it once i am getting syntax error while excuting the code ( compile error) this is the code but the logic in the update is by Grod Thompson Sub country()

Comment: Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Dim MySQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select Top 1 Table1.Country FROM Table1 ORDER BY Table1.Vol DESC")

MyCountry = rec(0)

rec.Close

MySQL = "UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.Country = DLookUp("Country","Table1","RB='" & RB & "' AND Plant='" & Plant & "' AND MCR='" & MCR & "' AND Country IS NOT NULL AND Vol=" & Nz(DMax("Vol","Table1","RB='" & RB & "' AND Plant='" & Plant & "' AND MCR='" & MCR & "' AND Country IS NOT NULL "),0)) WHERE (((Table1.Country) Is Null))"
DoCmd.RunSQL MySQL

db.Close
End Sub

Comment: @Johnny Bones and Gord Thompson did any one please help me i am still facing problem with this issue